# Create a button toolbar from button elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a **button toolbar** like so:

```
/------+--------+-------\
| left | middle | right |
\------+--------+-------/
```

All I have to do in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed8B7/), is to eliminate the margin between the buttons. But how to do this without using negative values for margin? Is this possible, or exists better ways to create a toolbar?

**HTML**:

```
<button class=left>left-button</button>
<button>middle-button</button>
<button class=right>right-button</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
button {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0;
}
.left {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.right {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `float:left;`

i also wrapped it with container so it will be centered, you can remove them if you want.

see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed8B7/4/)

hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces between the buttons as below:

```
<button class=left>left-button</button><button>middle-button</button><button class=right>right-button</button>
```

.

```
button {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ssd9/7/

Comment: Yes. While the other answers also contain solutions, this one actually addresses the cause of the problem, the whitespace between the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:left;` on the button.

```
button {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0;
    float:left;      /* Add this */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ed8B7/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here I have made the required changes please check the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Mohinder/vwK3Z/

what you need to do is make buttons `float:left;` remove right border from left button and left border from right button the way I have it on fiddle.

And if you want no border-between then add `class="mid"` to middle button and add `.mid { border-left:none; border-right:none; }` in your CSS